# Time-series forecasting: size of training data for cross-validation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, cross-validation, forecasting

Continuing my previous topic from here:

[Keras LSTM: a time-series multi-step multi-features forecasting - poor results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50742559/keras-lstm-a-time-series-multi-step-multi-features-forecasting-poor-results)

I would like to ask You about of strategy of finding the right network. I have read a lot about "test and trail" and "no rule for setting right size of hidden neuron"’.  From the other hand we have for instance a k-fold method for determining some of the network parameters.

The question is how to select enough input data for the k-fold or any other method to have my experiment finish in a reasonable time? Should it be whole data or a part of it? If a part, then what size would be appropriate?

Here is my input dataset description:

I have a time series dataset containing data from a whole year (date is the index). The data was measured every 15 min (during whole year) which results in 96 timesteps a day. The data is already normalized. The variables are correlated. All the variables except the VAR are weather measures.

VAR is seasonal in a day period and in a week period (as it looks a bit different on weekend, but more less the same every weekend). VAR values are stationary. 
I would like to predict values of VAR for next two days (192 steps ahead) and for next seven days (672 steps ahead).

Here is the sample of the dataset:

```
DateIdx               VAR       dewpt       hum         press       temp
2017-04-17 00:00:00   0.369397  0.155039    0.386792    0.196721    0.238889
2017-04-17 00:15:00   0.363214  0.147287    0.429245    0.196721    0.233333
2017-04-17 00:30:00   0.357032  0.139535    0.471698    0.196721    0.227778
2017-04-17 00:45:00   0.323029  0.127907    0.429245    0.204918    0.219444
2017-04-17 01:00:00   0.347759  0.116279    0.386792    0.213115    0.211111
2017-04-17 01:15:00   0.346213  0.127907    0.476415    0.204918    0.169444
2017-04-17 01:30:00   0.259660  0.139535    0.566038    0.196721    0.127778
2017-04-17 01:45:00   0.205564  0.073643    0.523585    0.172131    0.091667
2017-04-17 02:00:00   0.157650  0.007752    0.481132    0.147541    0.055556
2017-04-17 02:15:00   0.122101  0.003876    0.476415    0.122951    0.091667
```

[image: Input dataset plot]